# How to check if one character is next to another (Flesch index)?

Tags: python

I'm learning to work with strings and my project is to calculate the number of syllables in a sentence.

I'm given some code that calculates the syllables by adding to the variable, syllables += 1, for each vowel. But the end product is wrong because consecutive vowels should only count as a single +1. For example the word "certain" should return two syllables, not three. There is more to it than this but it's not relevant to my question.

Here is how I solved the problem, with an explanation below:

```
syllables = 0
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"

vowelContainer = "" # Part of my added code for solution. Create some container to hold 
                    # a representation of consecutive vowels.

for word in text.split():
    for vowel in vowels:
        syllables += word.count(vowel)
    for ending in ['es', 'ed', 'e']:
        if word.endswith(ending):
            syllables -= 1
    if word.endswith('le'):
        syllables += 1
    for vowel in word:                       # My added code for solution: rest of lines that follow
        if vowel == vowel in vowels:         # I fill in the container with Ts and Fs to create a string
            vowelContainer += "T"            # that I can then check for consecutive vowels.
        else:                                
            vowelContainer += "F"            
    count2ConsecutiveVowels = vowelContainer.count("TT")  # I count how many times there are two    
    count3ConsecutiveVowels = vowelContainer.count("TTT") # or three vowels in the word.
    syllables = syllables - count2ConsecutiveVowels - count3ConsecutiveVowels   # I subtract the count
    vowelContainer = ""                                                         # from total syllables
# At the end of the loop I empty the container for the next word.
```

I managed to come up with a solution, but it is messy. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Readability and programming! Love it.

Comment: `str.endswith` also accepts a tuple. You don't need to loop. You can give `word.endswith(('es', 'ed', 'e'))`

Comment: Also, you don't need to do `if vowel == vowel in vowels` just do `if vowel in vowels`. Both give you the same results.

Comment: Joe - thanks for pointing out my redundant logic. I guess I was thinking too visually of picking an item out of one box and comparing it to the item in the other box.

Comment: Joe - I'm not sure what you mean with the tuple comment. We are just reading about tuples right now in our textbook. The code with the endswith method was provided by the example, not something I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code should work:

```
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"

text = "certain"
syllables_count = 0

if len(text) == 1:
    if text[0] in vowels:
        syllables_count += 1
else:
    for i in range(len(text) - 1):
        if text[i] in vowels and text[i+1] not in vowels:
            syllables_count += 1
        elif text[i] in vowels and i+1 == len(text) - 1:
            syllables_count += 1
print(syllables_count)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! At first I was trying to do something like this but I kept running into an index out of range error. I think I understand now why that was happening with your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
vowels = "aeiou"
count = 0

with open("/home/doofinschmurts/PycharmProjects/Practice_001/text.txt", "r") as text:
    text = text.read()
for character in range(len(text) - 1):
    if text[character] in vowels and text[(character + 1)] not in vowels and text[character - 1] not in vowels:
        count += 1
    elif text[character] in vowels and text[character + 1] in vowels and text[character - 1] not in vowels:
        count += 1
    elif text[character] in vowels and text[character + 1] in vowels and text[character + 2] in vowels and text[character - 1] not in vowels:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

I'm new to coding but this script works and the main "jist" is in the long if statements. This wont be the best answer; however, if any veterans wouldn't mind critiquing me also.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the problem of consecutive vowels you mentioned above, and get the correct number of syllables, I suggest using a regular expression as in the following example:

```
    import re # put in the beginning to import regular expression module

    word='certaaaaiin' # just for example

    a=re.findall(r'[aeiouAEIOU](?![aeiouAEIOU])',word)
    syllables =len(a)

    print(syllables)
    # output is 2
```

In this method, any number of consecutive vowels is considered as one in counting

in the regular expression `[aeiouAEIOU](?![aeiouAEIOU])`, it selects any vowel in the list, in case of that vowel does not have another one after.

Comment: Thanks. This is a high school course and we haven't looked at this sort of thing yet. But I read up a little on regular expression and it looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you encounter a vowel, you need to increment the syllables counter by 1. Otherwise, you can ignore it.

Try this and see if this meets your needs.

```
text = input('Enter your word(s) :')

syllables = 0
vowels = "aeiou" #no need to check for upper and lower

for word in text.split():
    vowel_found = False                                 #initialize vowel_found to False and check if the world has vowels
    for char in word:                                   #iterate thru each char in the word
        if not vowel_found and char.lower() in vowels:  #for every new vowel found, increment syllables by 1
            syllables +=1
            vowel_found = True
        else:
            vowel_found = False                         #reset to increment counter again
print (syllables)
```

Here's the output I got:

```
Enter your word(s) :syllables
2

Enter your word(s) :certain
2

Enter your word(s) :book
1

Enter your word(s) :case
2

Enter your word(s) :Heart
1
```

Let me know if this code fails. I would like to improve this.

Comment: found my first issue: coapt, coed. These are 2 syllables while the code gives 1.

Comment: few more failures: mule (1 vs 2), mole (1 vs 2), male (1 vs 2) , coalition (4 vs 3). First number is correct number of syllables and second number is my code). In some it counts more and in others it counts less. However, if we use the logic, for every set of vowels, count as 1, then the logic works.

Comment: For some of the words you mention, it may just be that other parts of the code in the example are meant to catch this and not the code snippet you're working with that is relevant to my specific problem. Notice that in the code I gave there are loops catching words ending in le and ed (so you shouldn't expect your code to catch coed, mole, male, or mule). The rules of English syllables might be too complicated to catch with a single loop.